# Can NServiceBus have two endpoints with different handlers to receive different RabbitMQ events?

Tags: .net-core, rabbitmq, message-queue, nservicebus

We have two NServiceBus endpoints in a .Net Core 3.1 service using RabbitMQ as the transport. We're using two endpoints since we're subscribing to different events from different instances of Rabbit. We have event handlers created for the specific events from each of the RabbitMQ services.

When we create the first endpoint, we can go into RabbitMQ admin and see the bindings for our exchanges being set up correctly:

```
From:
Event1
nsb.delay-delivery
     ||
This Exchange
     ||
To:
Queue1
```

The problem is that the second endpoint isn't getting the same exchange binding setup. The code is the same for the creation of the endpoints, so we're not sure what's going wrong or how to debug it.
This is what the second exchange looks like:

```
From:
nsb.delay-delivery
   ||
This exchange
  ||
Queue2
```

Missing from the binding hierarchy is the Event2. If we go look at the exchange for Event2, there is no routing set up to our Queue2.

We've compared the *-configuration.txt files that are written to the .diagnostics directory of our service, but we see no difference between the logs for the two endpoints. When testing, our service does receive events from Queue1 in our handlers. We never see our handlers triggered for Queue2.

Has anyone successfully set up a service that can handle events from two different RabbitMQ services with two different endpoints?
What's the best way to go about debugging this? The NServiceBus documentation is a little limited on this part.

Comment: Effectively, these are two completely separate systems. Each have a RabbitMQ instance, an NServiceBus endpoint, a message type, and a handler for that message type. There's no reason that one of these systems should not work just because the other system exists.

Comment: Oh I agree. Which is why I'm confused as heck.

Comment: It may be best if you get in touch with us over one of our support channels — https://particular.net/support

Comment: Not sure if we have purchased support. Are there things I can try in order to debug this?

Comment: If you use "Request non-critical support" from that page, we'll get back to you.